# Problems when pulling git changes: uncommitted changes

Tags: git, github

I've got a serious trouble with git, in fact the `.gitignore` file, its is self writing, it has already 20k lines of the same text, /target, but the problem is this:

when I try to commit something I do:

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git pull
```

when I use the git pull I get an error saying that there are uncommited files on my work branch, and it's the .gitignore, I've tried to change my repo, but the problem keeps going, and i don't know what to do anymore.

if someone could help me, it would mean a lot because i got short time to deliver the project.

Comment: `git commit -m ""`. An empty commit message aborts the commit.

Comment: The best translation for your title I can get is "problems to give the git pull".  Can you do better?

Comment: the git commit -m "" was just to understand but i used the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, your `.gitignore` is full of garbage (20k lines of it) and you want to replace it with a good one.

Try the following:

Fetch latest changes from your remove repository (Github?).

`git fetch origin`

Replace .gitignore with the remote one (presumably good).

`git checkout .gitignore`

Now, the result of `git status` should not list `.gitignore` as a changed file. After that, you can edit your `.gitignore` and commit it.

Note: the git book is [available in Portuguese](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br)

Comment: no it`s not that, the problem is i that when i stash or delete or edit the .gitignore file, it starts rewriting everithing again so when i try to push, i can`t because the file is diferent from the one i commited...

Comment: Can you provide more details of your set up? I presume you're using Maven, Eclipse, eGit?